# How to use sub query inside the parent query giving the sub query another condition?

Tags: mysql

I have question regarding sub query, I have a module where i need to sum the net sales having a interval of 7 days based on upload date. so each

**Note:stores has a corresponding record of sales.**

So now I have parent select where the condition is to sub date the current date.
inside of the parent select, I insert sub query where the condition interval of 7 days. but badly i got error subquery returns more than 1 row. so lets move forward I will show you guys my script that i created.

**Error:**

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

**The parent query:**

```
SELECT 

    storeid,
    company,
    market as store,

    /* part 1 */
    CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(ns), 0)) as NS, 
    CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(nstgt), 0)) as NSTGT,
    CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(ns) / SUM(nstgt)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "nstgt_percentage",
    /* part 1 end*/



    /* part 2 */
    CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(nsly), 0)) as nsly,
    CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(ns) / SUM(nsly)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "nsly_percentage",
    /* part 2 end */


    /* part 3 */
    CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(tc), 0)) as TC, 
    CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(tctgt), 0)) as TCTGT,
    CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(tc) / SUM(tctgt)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "tctgt_percentage",
    /* part 3 end */

    /* part 4 */
    CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(tcly), 0)) as tcly,
    CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(tc) / SUM(tcly)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "tcly_percentage",
    /* part 4 end */

    /* part 5 */
    ROUND((SUM(ns) / SUM(tc)),1)  as "TA",
    ROUND((SUM(nstgt) / SUM(tctgt)),1)  as "TATGT",
    ROUND((SUM(nsly) / SUM(tcly)),1)  as "TALY"
    /* part 5 end */

    FROM xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx as sales_report1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT store_code,market,company FROM xxxx.xxxxxxx) sm 
    ON sales_report1.storeid = sm.store_code
    WHERE market = "CGY" AND
    week = (SELECT DISTINCT(week) FROM xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx WHERE txndate = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2))
    AND period = (SELECT DISTINCT(period) FROM xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx WHERE txndate = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2)) AND (nsly != "." OR tcly != ".") GROUP BY storeid
```

**My Subquery:**

```
    (
    select 
    ns

    FROM xxxx.xxxxxx as sales_report1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT store_code,market FROM xxx.xxxxx) sm 
    ON sales_report1.storeid = sm.store_code
    WHERE market = "CGY" AND
    week = (SELECT DISTINCT(week) FROM xxxxx.xxxxxxx WHERE uploaddate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY GROUP BY uploaddate)  
    AND period = (SELECT DISTINCT(period) FROM xxxx.xxxxxxxx WHERE uploaddate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY GROUP BY uploaddate)

) as nslw,
```

**Full Query:**

```
SELECT 

sales_report1.storeid,
company,
market as store,

/* part 1 */
CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(ns), 0)) as NS, 
CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(nstgt), 0)) as NSTGT,
CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(ns) / SUM(nstgt)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "nstgt_percentage",
/* part 1 end*/

/* part 2 */
CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(nsly), 0)) as nsly,
CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(ns) / SUM(nsly)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "nsly_percentage",
/* part 2 end */


/* part 3 */
CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(tc), 0)) as TC, 
CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(tctgt), 0)) as TCTGT,
CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(tc) / SUM(tctgt)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "tctgt_percentage",
/* part 3 end */

/* part 4 */
CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(tcly), 0)) as tcly,
CONCAT(ROUND(TRUNCATE(((SUM(tc) / SUM(tcly)-1) * 100),2),1),"%")  as "tcly_percentage",
/* part 4 end */

/* part 5 */
ROUND((SUM(ns) / SUM(tc)),1)  as "TA",
ROUND((SUM(nstgt) / SUM(tctgt)),1)  as "TATGT",
ROUND((SUM(nsly) / SUM(tcly)),1)  as "TALY",
/* part 5 end */

(
    select 
    CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(ns), 0))
    FROM cron_db.sales_report_export_1 as sales_report1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT store_code,market FROM cron_db.store_master) sm 
    ON sales_report1.storeid = sm.store_code
    WHERE 
    week IN (SELECT DISTINCT(week) FROM cron_db.sales_report_export_2 WHERE txndate = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2))
    and period IN (SELECT DISTINCT(period) FROM cron_db.sales_report_export_1 WHERE uploaddate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY GROUP BY uploaddate)
) as nslw



FROM cron_db.sales_report_export_1 as sales_report1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT store_code,market,company FROM cron_db.store_master) sm 
ON sales_report1.storeid = sm.store_code
WHERE market = "CGY"
AND week = (SELECT DISTINCT(week) FROM cron_db.sales_report_export_1 WHERE txndate = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2))
AND period = (SELECT DISTINCT(period) FROM cron_db.sales_report_export_1 WHERE txndate = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2)) AND (nsly != "." OR tcly != ".") 
GROUP BY sales_report1.storeid
```

**The Output that i got in my subquery:**

[output of my subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHria.png)

**Sample output must be in my subquery:**

[output must be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKl32.png)

Thank you.

Comment: why give down vote? do you guys not understand my question? thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sorry for that, thank you for the correcting me.. i will replace my script

Comment: @SoulAiker your question is not making much sense, `sales_report1` does not have any reference of `sales_report2`

Comment: @SudiptaMondal i already change sorry for that.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal  sudipta do you know why does sub query not working?

Comment: If you are using `Sub Query` in your select statement, and it returns more than 1 ` record`, your query will give you the error message. Also if you use `Sub Query` in your where condition, you can use `IN` instead of `=` in there where clause condition

Comment: @SudiptaMondal how can i use the group by in the subquery? because when i group by the storeid return row 1? can you help me about this?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal please see the new update. thanks

Comment: @SoulAiker if your subquery returns the same value in 6 rows, just use distinct function in the select clause. If it returns different values, then you need to JOIN your other tables with your sub query,

Comment: @SudiptaMondal can you give me example please..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have combined these 2 queries as you have presented them separately. Most of the time we get the error ***Subquery returns more than 1 row*** when we combine queries using **=**.

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM Products)
```

To avoid this we can use **IN** keyword.

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Price IN 
      (SELECT Price 
       FROM Products
       Where ExpDate>xxxxxxx)
```

Comment: how can i use that in my query?

Comment: @SoulAiker As I mentioned It's difficult to understand the connection between your parent and subquery. Can you provide a full query?

Comment: Where exactly you use the output(nslw) of a subquery